# Understanding next middle-ware in the scope of express.js / sail.js controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, express, sails.js

I am using sails.js which is built on top of express.js . 
In my routes.js I defined a route like following

```
'/account/login': {
      controller    : 'Session',
      action        : 'logInAPI'
  },
```

And my session controller is like this

```
logInAPI: function(req, res, next) {
        if (!req.param('email') || !req.param('password')) {

            var usernamePasswordRequiredError = [
                'You must enter a username and a password.'
            ]

            req.session.flash = {
                err: usernamePasswordRequiredError
            }

            return next();
                }
            else{// Log in user};
  }
```

I am wondering when I am calling next where does it pointing to in middlewear. What will happen if just write return; Instead of return next();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you call `next()` instead of just returning some value is to allow asynchronous serial chaining of middleware operations. For example:

```
function(req, res, next){
  setTimeout(next, 1000);
}
```

This is an example of a useless middleware that does nothing except delay the response for one second. Note specifically that in this case, `next()` executes *after* the function returns.

In a more realistic scenario, `setTimeout()` would of course be replaced by some logic that does a database fetch and accepts a callback, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I am wondering in the scope of sail.js how controller works. So when I call next which function in the middleware get executed after calling the logInAPI function.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with sail.js. In Express, `next()` passes control to the next middleware, in the order declared in the code. Also you don't always need to call next. If you do `req.end()` for example, you don't necessarily need to pass control to the next thing. Sorry couldn't be of more help.

Comment: In express do you know where I can find the middleware stack to see which function is calling after which function.

Comment: In vanilla Express, you'd write the middleware stack yourself. Briefly perusing the sail.js documentation, my guess is that your controller runs at the end of the middleware stack, and that a "policy" is a piece of middleware that you can (optionally) insert before your controller in the stack. In the two minutes I spent, I didn't see any examples of a sail.js controller calling `next()`.